# time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(myFile)) results in TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Tags: python

Newbie question here.

I'm trying the code provided from: [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

The exact code I'm running is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os.path, time
myFile = open('IMG_4847.PNG', 'rb')
print "last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(myFile))
```

But, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
   print "last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(myFile))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 54, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

```
import os.path, time
print "last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime('IMG_4847.PNG'))
```

You pass a filepath to `getmtime`, not a file object.